# multi tabbed SSH client using screen

Tags: ssh, gnu-screen

Is there an SSH client that can present a client side GUI interface to the [screen](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-to-use-screen-command-under-linux.html)* program?

I'm thinking of an SSH program that would hook in with screen's session handling and map client side actions (clicking on a tab, ctrl-tab, scrolling, possibly even allowing several tabs to be seen at the same time) to whatever it takes to make screen at the other end do it's thing.

`*` The [screen](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-to-use-screen-command-under-linux.html) program that allow multiple virtual consoles under a single terminal session, for example you can run several apps under a single SSH connection and switch between them as well as other cool things.

Comment: Are you asking for a screen scraper?   Not clear what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

An interesting idea, and quite possible (vim7's tabs show as clicky GUI tabs in gnome-terminal), but I don't see the benefit of doing this..

Using the follow `~/.screenrc` shows "graphical" tabs:

```
startup_message off
vbell off
hardstatus alwayslastline
hardstatus string '%{gk}[ %{G}%H %{g}][%= %{wk}%?%-Lw%?%{=b kR}(%{W}%n*%f %t%?(%u)%?%{=b kR})%{= kw}%?%+Lw%?%?%= %{g}]%{=y C}[%d/%m %c]%{W}'
```

..which look like the following (after renaming the tabs using `ctrl+a,a`:

[x http://img216.imageshack.us/img216/9401/picture4myi.png](http://img216.imageshack.us/img216/9401/picture4myi.png)

You can scroll around in a screen session using "copy mode", by doing `ctrl+a,[` and using the cursor keys (press `Esc` or `ctrl+c` to exit it)

You can also attach to the same screen session multiple times using the `screen -x` flag (rather than `-r`), so you could use any tabbed terminal emulator, and open one tab for each screen-window.

If you really did want to start implementing this - one option would be to look into modifying gnome-terminal, to copy the behaviour with vim's tabs for screen. Or, write your own screen client - you don't need to do anything as fragile sounding as scraping the terminal - there's a FIFO file in (usually) `/tmp/uscreens/S-$USER/$PID.sessionname` which I think is how screen communicates, and remember screen is [open-source](http://directory.fsf.org/project/screen/)!

Answer (score 1):

Interesting idea. I use screen everyday both on my local machine and for SSH sessions. I think your biggest problem is that I suspect most screen users are commandline junkies like me who just won't see the benefit of making a gui for tabs. In fact, I have all my terminals in one gnome-terminal window under different tabs, and having screen's text-based tabs is a nice way not to confuse the two.

I suspect it could be done, but you'd be writing a specialised terminal emulator which analyses screen's output (custom .screenrc) and retrofits the gui.

A lot of work for minimal gain.

Comment: now days, even CLI junkies run several consoles under a GUI. If done right, it would be just about the same.

Answer (score 1):

ctrl+a shift+'

.. gui front-end to screen?  what are you talking about??

also, because my rep is so low, and i cant comment, id like to LOL @ geoffc for his comment in the question

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen one, but the following may help you. Add to your .screenrc

To show a row of "tabs" on the bottom
caption always  "%{.bW}%-Lw%{.rW}%n %t%{-}%+Lw %=%{..G} %{..Y} %m/%d"

To show the current program as the screen name [assuming you're using bash and your prompt ends with "$ " by default; others shells are the exact same idea]

shelltitle "$ |sh"